# How can i access simulink by python?

Tags: python, matlab, simulink

I want to search inside a simulink model for a particular object and point out it's directory.(Model path).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtaining the model topology from a Simulink model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141062/obtaining-the-model-topology-from-a-simulink-model)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you: http://www.fauskes.net/nb/parsing-simulink/
But starting with Matlab 2012 there ist also a binary format which consists of zipped xml files.If you have this format you will need to use an xml parser.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just run a MATLAB script that does a find_system on model filenames passed in and spits out the names of the blocks, thus avoiding any compatibility issues.